# Covariance of Asymptotic Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose I have two random variables indexed by n  that behave equivalent to

$$X + O(n) \hspace{6mm} Y + O(n)$$

Where $X\sim f_x$  and $Y\sim f_y$ have their own respective governing probability laws.

I am interested in finding

$$\text{cov}\left((X+O(n))^2,(Y+O(n))^2\right).$$

I figured that this is equivalent to

$$\text{cov}\left(X^2,Y^2\right) +O(n).$$

A simple expansion of the quadratic results in the following

$$\text{cov}\left((X+O(n))^2,(Y+O(n))^2\right)=\text{cov}\left(X^2,Y^2\right) + 4O(n)O(n)\text{cov}\left(X,Y\right)+2O(n)\text{cov}\left(X^2,Y\right) +2O(n)\text{cov}\left(Y^2,X\right).$$

By assuming finite covariances then I get what I predict. Is my logic correct? Can I find a quicker decay rate?

Comment: If you have random variables of the form $X + cn$ and $Y + c'n$ for some constants $c,c'$, what is their variance? What is their covariance?

Comment: @Galton Since cn is a constant then their variance and covariance is just  that of $X$ and $Y$ but its the squaring that leads to the $O(n)$ by having it being a leading term of a component that does not equal zero. At least that is what makes sense to me.

Comment: In your last equation, wouldn't you get $4cc' n^2$? Why does the square disappear? Other than that, I don't see issues with your logic. Your example explicitly shows that $O(n^2)$ cannot be improved (take $X=Y$ standard normal) unless you put conditions on the relationship between $X$ and $Y$

Comment: @Galton You are correct. I mistakenly wrote $O(n)$ when I intended decay instead of growth $O(n^{-1})$.